# PowerBuilder .NET: This application needs a script for its open event

Tags: powerbuilder

Ok, so I'm building my first PowerBuilder app for a client using WPF. I've got a simple form with a couple of buttons. When I try to run it I get this error message:

> This application needs a script for its open event.

So, what is it expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Open ( w_window )
```

where w_window is the name of the main form.

Comment: It can be any set of PowerScript, but yes, if you want to see your form, you need to Open() the window. Many apps use this point to set up environments, connect to databases, etc.... (Not suggesting these are best practices, but pointing out there is some flexibility in what can be done in the Open event of an application.)

Comment: Feel like entering an answer with what you think are the best practices?

Comment: Fortunately for me, not enough room in a comment for a full answer. <g> Short answer: application object is not reusable, classes (custom classes aka non-visual user objects) are. If you want to start thinking about reuse, put your application start code in a class and call the class method from the application Open. If this is a one-off experiment or uniquely purposed app, don't over-architect, and anything goes as long as it works. JMHO